# How to get the logs from previous build in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins Pipeline, the first stage executes a freestyle job. Therefore, I need to get the output/logs from that job because it will return a string of IPs which will be used on my second stage.

```
def getEc2ListResult = []
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }

stages{
    stage('Get EC2 List'){
        steps {
            script {
                def getEc2List = build job: 'get-ec2-by-tag', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'envTagValue', value: "${envTagValue}"),
                    string(name: 'OS', value: "${OS}")
                ]
                getEc2ListResult = getEc2List.getPreviousBuild().getLog(20)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.getLog() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [20]
Possible solutions: getId(), getAt(java.lang.String), getClass()
```

Answer (score 3):

`getEc2List` is of type [RunWrapper](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java), also `getEc2List.getPreviousBuild()`.

`RunWrapper` doesn't supply a `getLog()` api, it is supplied by [rawBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html).

you can get `getEc2List`'s rowBuild by call `getEc2List.rawBuild` or `getEc2List.getRawBuild()`.

But `getRawBuild()` is not in `@Whitelisted` of `RunWrapper`, so you will get following message in jenkins log:

> Scripts not permitted to use method
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
>   getRawBuild. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject
>   this signature.

One option, it's to ask Jenkins admin to change Script Approve

Another option, it's do as following:

```
stage('') {

    environment {
      JENKINS_AUTH = credentials('<credentail id of jenkins auth>')
      // add an credentail with a jenkins user:password before use it at here
    }

    steps {
        script {
            def getEc2List = build job: 'get-ec2-by-tag', parameters: [
                string(name: 'envTagValue', value: "${envTagValue}"),
                string(name: 'OS', value: "${OS}")
            ]
            logUrl = getEc2List.absoluteUrl + 'consoleText'

            log = sh(script: 'curl -u {JENKINS_AUTH} -k' + logUrl, 
                     returnStdout: true).trim()

            // parse the log to extract the ip
            ...
        }
    }

}
```